# ASCII + Unicode art in LaTeX lstlisting

Tags: listings

I have a small ASCII diagram in my LaTeX document.

```
\lstset{literate={↓}{$\downarrow{}$}{1}}
\begin{lstlisting}
-1---2----3-----|
---s---------s--|
   ↓         ↓
---1*--------3***|
\end{lstlisting}
```

Adding the down arrow was hard enough already, but now the `---` on the second line is converted to a horizontal line, and to larger minus signs on the bottom line. Especially the last line is wider than it should be.

[image: Image 1 generated as PDF]

I have another one that looks even worse:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
-4--5--7--3----|
---s--s--s--s--|
   ↓  \-↓   \-↓
---4****5*****3***|
\end{lstlisting}
```

The entire bottom line is misaligned:

[image: Image 2 generated as PDF]

How do I make it look more like the original ASCII?

Comment: You're using a proportional font

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Haven't set the font anywhere. But that could very well be the problem.

Comment: The font is set by the document class by default, unless changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characters in most fonts do not have the same width, i.e. a 't' might be narrower than the letter `a`, the character width of the fonts are proportional then.

If all characters should have the same width, use a non-proportional font, such as `typewriter` font (e.g. Courier), which is enabled, for example with `\ttfamily`.

In addition I suggest to use the `inputenc` package to provide support for direct input of unicode characters (or use `xelatex` then) to make `UnicodeArt` ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily},literate={↓}{$\downarrow{}$}{1}}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}  
1---2----3-----|
---s---------s--|  
  ↓         ↓  
---1*--------3***|  
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}  
---s---------s--|  
    ↓         ↓  
---1*--------3***|  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh that easy? It works now!

Comment: Interesting how the horizontal alignment is off slightly...

Answer (score 4):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) is a viable option, but there are some minor alignment issues. Here are two alternatives using [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) and a regular `verbatim` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\da}{% down arrow
  \phantom{x}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{$\downarrow$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,literate={↓}{$\downarrow{}$}{1}]
 ---s---------s--|
    ↓         ↓
 ---1*--------3***|
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
 ---s---------s--|
    \da         \da
 ---1*--------3***|
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{verbatim}
 ---s---------s--|
    |         |
    v         v
 ---1*--------3***|
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
1---2----3--------|
 ---s---------s---|  
    ↓         ↓  
 ---1*--------3***|  
\end{Verbatim}

\bigskip
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]  
----s---------s---|  
    ↓         ↓  
----1*--------3***|  
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

and if you prefer `pdflatex` then use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{↓}{$\downarrow$}
\begin{document}
[...]
\end[document}
```

[image]